# Send .txt file, document file to the server in android

Tags: android, file, client-server

I am developing an application in which I am sending data in string format to the server. Below is my code. It is working fine. But now my question is how can I send whole .txt file and .doc file to the server. In my GUI I have to provide path of user choice. Means user has to choose the path of file that he/she wants to send...Please help me to solve my problem...Thank you...

activity_main.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/ip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/port"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/msg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:text="@string/send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

.java file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private EditText etMsg, etIP, etPort;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;
    int port = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        etMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                messsage = etMsg.getText().toString();
                etMsg.setText("");
                port = Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString());

                new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try 
                        {
                            client = new Socket(etIP.getText().toString(), port);
                            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                            printwriter.write(messsage);
                            printwriter.flush();
                            printwriter.close();
                            client.close();
                        }

                        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }       
                    }
                }).start();


            }
        });
    }

}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: use this link http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

Comment: @DixitPatel : Thanks...Let me implement it...

Answer (score 6):

Try this code.. this is perfectly working for me..

```
public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    final String uploadFilePath = "mypath";
     final String uploadFileName = "myfile";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- 'path"+uploadFileName+"'");


        upLoadServerUri = "serverpath";

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                             {
                                    public void run() 
                                    {
                                        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                    }
                                });                      

                             uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                        }
                      }).start();        
                }
            });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri)
    {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile())
          {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                   +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
               {
                   public void run() 
                   {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try 
               { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) 
                   {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200)
                   {

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                       {
                            public void run()
                            {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"+" serverpath"
                                              +uploadFileName;

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } 
               catch (MalformedURLException ex) 
               {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                  {
                      public void run() 
                      {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } 
               catch (Exception e) 
               {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } 
         }
     }
```

Hope this will help u :-)

Comment: What should I write on my server file?

Comment: Hi,  how can i upload file to server without using any progress bar or anything. just upload file to server in background. like create a function upload(String FileName) and then upload file to server in background whenever this function is called. what should i add to the function in order to acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
DataInputStream inputStream = null;
String pathToOurFile = "/data/file_to_send.mp3";
String urlServer = "http://192.168.1.1/handle_upload.php";
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

try
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Set HTTP method to POST.
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead &gt; 0)
    {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Exception handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code uploads data (images, mp3′s, text files etc..) to HTTP server

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
DataInputStream inputStream = null;

String pathToOurFile = "/data/file_to_send.mp3";
String urlServer = "http://192.168.1.1/handle_upload.php";
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

try
{
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

URL url = new URL(urlServer);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Allow Inputs & Outputs
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);

// Enable POST method
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/formdata;boundary="+boundary);

outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// Read file
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

// Responses from the server (code and message)
serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

fileInputStream.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Exception handling
  }
```

Comment: @Gaurav...How can I set IP and Port number of server on which I have to send files...???

Comment: @ Anil Bhatiya at initial lines i have given the string for IP address

Comment: @Gaurav...Ya it is fine. But without port number will it work???and Is it neccesary to write IP after http...???

Comment: @Gaurav...I wrote String urlServer = "http://192.168.1.1" but output is force close...

Answer (score 1):

try this code to create txt file write string to that file and send it to server...

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"new");
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            f.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File("new.txt");
        FileWriter w = new FileWriter("/sdcard/new/new.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(w);
        out.write(data);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
                          String file_name = "/sdcard/new/new.txt";

        File file1 = new File(file_name);  
        socket = new Socket("117.218.28.70", 2020);

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());  
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  

        oos.writeObject(file1.getName());  

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);  
        byte [] buffer = new byte[450000];  
        Integer bytesRead = 0;  

        while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) 
        {  
            oos.writeObject(bytesRead);  
            oos.writeObject(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length));  
        }  
        oos.close();  
        ois.close();  
        System.exit(0);
```