# How to upload image and any doc file to server from app in convenient way

Tags: php, android, eclipse, file-upload

How can i upload image and any doc file( for e.g. *.doc or *.pdf) from app to PHP server in very convenient way(it does not take much time to upload and should compress image or doc while uploading and decompress it on other side).

Please refer to me some good example to do both in android app or any library for eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below Link it will help you.

[Send .txt file, document file to the server in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351870/send-txt-file-document-file-to-the-server-in-android)

http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/image-upload-on-server.html